# What should I look for in a platform to make my project easy to edit?

Tags: contributor, software, accessibility

To clarify, since I don't know if "platform" is the right word: I'm talking about things like GitHub or the late Google Code.

What features should I look for in a code publishing platform so that people can suggest patches as easily as possible, and preferably have them approved as easily as possible?

Note that I'm *not* talking about publicizing it, attracting developers, or anything like that.

Comment: This is sort of asking for a platform recommendation (which is very broad), perhaps your question would be along the lines of "what features of repositories would I look for to ..."

Comment: @Raystafarian Maybe. I'm not entirely sure how to phrase it, but I like your idea better. Edited.

Comment: Platform is a word you could use. A better word would be 'repository'.

Comment: What kind of project? Different communities like different tools, so there isn't a universal answer.